# Algorithm for sorting some nodes

Tags: algorithm, nodes

I am trying to find a suitable algorithm to solve this: suppose I have some (oriented graph) nodes. Each node might have or not a parent (meaning at most one parent). Suppose this notation for a node: (id, id_parent). Some nodes will be (id_i, NULL) while there will be nodes (id_j, id_i) as "sons" of id_i . Having an array of these nodes in a particular order, I want to get them sorted in this order: parent-son-son of son-son-son of son, etc.

Example: nodes (1, NULL), (2,NULL), (3,1), (4,3), (5,2), (6,3)

The sorted array will be: (1,NULL), (3,1), (4,3), (6,3), (2, NULL), (5,2) . A kind of in-depth tree exploration.

Which algorithm would be suitable for achieving this?  Thanks

Comment: what happens if 2 nodes have the same children? Do they appear twice? Once?

Comment: there is not such possibility. each node has a single parent

Comment: Could you elaborate on your example? I'm still not clear what is the sorted order you're referring to. I'm leaning towards a post order traversal though, from what little I understand.

Comment: how can I know, you say an `oriented graph`. And [it may occurs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OrientedGraph.html) in an oriented graph

Comment: because I said: "Each node might have or not a parent."

Comment: change it to "each node have at most one parent"

Answer (score 2):

If the graph has no cycles - it is a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), and you are looking for [topoloical sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_ordering).

If it has cycles - there is no such ordering, since in the cycle, there will be a node, which its son is also its ancestor.

EDIT:
If the graph is a forest (disjoint union of trees) - then a simple [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) on it from sources will do. Just construct the graph (It is `O(nlogn)` to sort, if it is not already sorted, or `O(n)` using [radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)), find the list of sources, and do the DFS from each source, and each time you visit a node, store it in an output array. Iterate while there are undiscovered vertices.

Comment: It's like a tree,no cycles. I've been thinking that is topological sort, but I dont think it is.

Comment: @Madrugada I am sorry, I misunderstood the description of the problem - is that better?